nginx config - not correctly using server_name value
I have ensured that nginx is loading the correct config, and there is no other config files. Deploying nginx container using docker compose.
I am using cloudflare's DNS to create an A record to pointto the server's public ip.
nginx seems to always use the defualt_server no matter what.
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 403;
}

server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomainhere.com;

  root /var/www/html;

  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wp1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }

}


Why is it tagged with docker and virtual-machines?

I see that you've defined two server blocks in the Nginx configuration file:
The first server block is:
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 403;
}

The above has the following server_name directive with no parameter defined:
server_name _;

The second server block is:
server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomainhere.com;

It's server_name directive is configured as:
server_name mydomainhere.com;

Now, it's likely that Nginx server is detecting two server blocks, which make it believe that there are two website configurations in the file.
You could try to assign each server_name directive in each server block with the unique parameters.
For the first server block include the directive with your suitable domain. For example:
server_name example1.com;

For the second server block, do the same with a different domain:
server_name example2.com;

However, if you're simply running a single website, then just remove the first server block in the configuration file:
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 403;
}

If you removed the first server block, make sure the second server block has the right domain name configured:
server_name example.com;

References:

How to Configure Nginx to host multiple websites

How to install Nginx Server on Linux

How to Configure Nginx to host a PHP site with a Database

How to use Cloudflare on Namecheap Domain Pointed to Contabo



Your second server block is listening to only IPv6 traffic.
Add
listen 80;

to the second server block to allow it listen on IPv4 traffic..
